# Alter all table with prefixe

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a SQL code allowing to alter all table with a prefixe word :

I got many table names XXXX_users and i would like to add a column to each. Is it possible to do it with just one row with something like :

> ALTER TABLE %_users

I use PHPMyAdmin for the database management.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably not.  I don't know of any database that supports this.  But you should include the database you are using as a tag.

Comment: I think you need to use catalog information and dynamic SQL to do this without specifying each table manually.

Comment: that's what i thought too ... Let's do it one by one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 'dynamic MySQL' ('dynamic SQL'), auto generate the ALTER statements with this:

```
   SELECT CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ', table_name, ' TO XXXX_', table_name, ';' ) alter_table_stmt
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables t
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('<DB SCHEMA NAME>');
```

then execute the generated statements as a batch.